# Python static method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Object oriented python, I want to create a static method to convert hours, minutes and seconds into seconds.

I create a class called Duration:

```
    class Duration:
        def __init__(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
            self.hours = hours
            self.minutes = minutes
            self.seconds = seconds
```

I then create a variable named duration1 where I give it the numbers

```
duration1 = Duration(29, 7, 10)
```

I have a method called info which checks if any of the numbers are less than 10, and if so add a "0" in front of it, and then i later revert the values into ints.

```
def info(self):
    if self.hours < 10:
        self.hours = "0" + str(self.hours)

    elif self.minutes < 10:
        self.minutes = "0" + str(self.minutes)

    elif self.seconds < 10:
        self.seconds = "0" + str(self.seconds)

    info_string = str(self.hours) + "-" + str(self.minutes) + "-" + str(self.seconds)
    self.hours = int(self.hours)
    self.minutes = int(self.minutes)
    self.seconds = int(self.seconds)
    return info_string
```

And now  I want to create a static_method to convert these values into seconds, and return the value so i can call it with duration1 (atleast I think thats how i should do it..?

```
@staticmethod
def static_method(self):
    hour_to_seconds = self.hours * 3600
    minutes_to_seconds = self.minutes * 60
    converted_to_seconds = hours_to_seconds + minutes_to_seconds \
    + self.seconds
    return converted_to_seconds

duration1.static_method(duration1.info())
```

I guess my question is how would I use a static method with this code to change the numbers? I should also tell you this is a school assignment so I have to use a static method to solve the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Error message says this:

```
hour_to_seconds = self.hours * 3600
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hours'

Comment: A static method,  by definition, is not a method of an instance. Therefore, it cannot have a `self` parameter.

Comment: static method doesn't take self parameter as it can be called outside a class object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

Instead of passing the result of `duration1.info()` to `duration1.static_method()`, you simply pass the whole object:

```
duration1 = Duration(29, 7, 10)
print(duration1.info()) # 29-07-10
print(duration1.static_method(duration1)) # 104830
```

And since it's a static method, you could just as well call it from the class instead of the instance (which is the reason why one wants a static method - you don't have to create an instance):

```
print(Duration.static_method(duration1))
```

By the way, as a convention `self` should not be used as the parameter name if you're using it in a static method, but it works anyway, because - as I said - it's just a convention. It's not as if `self` is a "magic" variable.

But you should consider to rename the parameter.

By the way, you have a typo in `static_method`, once you call the variable `hour_to_seconds` but then access `hours_to_seconds` - you need to decide on one.

Answer (score 0):

A static method is *explicitly* a function which is tied to a class rather than an instance. `self` in Python represents an instance of a class in Python.

These are not simpatico.

You can make your code work by passing `duration1` to your static method and changing the name of its accepted parameter from `self` to `duration` or similar.